# what does .space do in mips?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mips32

I got this problem for an assignment in which we have put these number in an array and add them without using a loop. I have solved this problem but .space is confusing me. By making .space 20 do i make space for 5 words or is it doing something else.

> ```
>  .data
>   array: .space 20
>  .text
> addi $s0, $zero, 2
> addi $s1, $zero, 12
> addi $s2, $zero, -5
> addi $s3, $zero, 7
> addi $s4, $zero, 4
>   addi $t0, $zero,0  #index initialized at 0
> sw $s0,array($t0) 
> addi $t0, $t0, 4
> sw $s1,array($t0) 
> addi $t0, $t0, 4
> sw $s2,array($t0) 
> addi $t0, $t0, 4
> sw $s3,array($t0) 
> addi $t0, $t0, 4
> sw $s4,array($t0) 
> addi $t0, $t0, 4
> ```

Comment: Yes, it does make space for 5 words. Consult your assembler's manual, [this is for gas](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Space.html).

Answer (score 11):

`.space Len` directive instructs the assembler to reserve Len bytes.
As every word has 4 bytes, when Len is 20 you are instructing the assembler to reserve 5 words.

For example if you have

```
.data
array: .space 20
other_data: .asciiz 'This is other data'
```

then `other_data` will be 20 bytes after `array` address.

Due to architectural constraints in MIPS you may need to also instruct the assembler to align the reserved memory (`.align 2`) before your array label if you want to access on a word-by-word basis (in your particular example you would not need it, it should be already aligned).